# error - opening session failed as protocol [name] is not declared

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I'm trying to connect a heart rate monitor via bluetooth. I have the device's SDK. 
When I instantiate an object of type `HRMonitor` - it's delegate prints `connectionChanged`

Probably connected and working fine.

But right after that I get the folowing output:

> 2013-04-10 11:36:00.409 TestHRMonitor[601:907] connectionChanged
>
> 2013-04-10 11:36:00.415 TestHRMonitor[601:907] ERROR - opening session
>   failed as protocol com.ssiamerica.ipulse is not declared in Info.plist
>
> 2013-04-10 11:36:00.417 TestHRMonitor[601:907] ERROR -
>   /SourceCache/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-213.3/EASession.m:-[EASession
>   dealloc] - 137 unable to close session for _accessory=0x1fd26e70 and
>   sessionID=65536

I only have *.h,*.a files.

Sorry, I know this is a newbe's question but:

Can anyone please explain more about this error, and how do I declare this protocol in Info.plist?

[EDITED]I've worked this out.

All I needed to do is:
1. Open info.Plist
2. Add a key "Supported external accessory protocol. 
3. add to the key the value [name] that was stated inside the error description.

Comment: What is HRMonitor ? Regarding the error, it looks like something called a session can not be closed as it was not opened or opened correctly.

Comment: HRMonitor is the class implemented in the SDK

Comment: I don't think so, https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=HRMonitor - No results were found for HRMonitor. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer` doesn't have any files with "HRMonitor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked this out.

All I needed to do is:

1. Open info.Plist
2. Add a key "Supported external accessory protocol.
3. add to the key the value [name] that was stated inside the error description.